# How to include some lines of text and an image on every page in Markdown?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

So I have to prepare a document in markdown, in which I have to sign my name (picture of my signature + some text) on every page in the pdf output. I'm using RStudio to generate pdf from markdown, presumably with `pandoc` being the underlying converter.

Is there a way to do this? It's especially difficult since the location of the page changes every time there's new content added, and markdown, unlike Latex, doesn't seem to be a page-based format.

Comment: The [original Markdown implementation](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) "is a text-to-HTML conversion tool for web writers". It doesn't support PDF output at all, and HTML doesn't really have the concept of pages. Are you using another tool to generate your output? That is important information to add to your question.

Comment: I'm using markdown in R studio, which has pdf as an option. They must be using pandoc I suppose

Comment: in Pandoc you can use a [template](http://pandoc.org/README.html#templates) and insert a LaTeX command to put something on every page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandoc relies on latex. You can use `header-includes` in the yaml front matter to add content to the latex header. Here, you could define a header with `fancyhdr`:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    - \pagestyle{fancy}
    - \rhead{right header text}
    - \lhead{left header text}
    - \cfoot{center footer text}
output: pdf_document
---
```

You'll find more on customizing Latex headers in any Latex manual, like this [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Customizing_with_fancyhdr).